# Is a map inducing surjections on all stable homotopy groups $\pi_k$ an epimorphism in the stable homotopy category?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of spectra. The associated morphism in the stable homotopy category is an epimorphism, if and only if it fits into a distinguished triangle
$$
X\xrightarrow{f} Y\xrightarrow{0}Z.
$$
(By abuse of notation, I use the same symbol ''$f$'' here for the induced morphism in the stable homotopy category.) From this we get a long exact sequence on stable homotopy groups and the induced morphisms on stable homotopy groups $\pi_k(f)\colon \pi_k(X)\to\pi_k(Y)$ are all surjective. I wonder whether the converse is true:

> Is $f$ an epimorphism in the stable homotopy category **if** it induces surjections $\pi_k(f)\colon \pi_k(X)\to\pi_k(Y)$ on all stable homotopy groups?

(I guess the answer is 'no' but I cannot find a counterexample.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $f: X\to Y$ is a non-zero morphism in the stable homotopy category inducing the zero map on all homotopy groups (according to [Is this morphism of spectra zero in the stable homotopy category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093343/is-this-morphism-of-spectra-zero-in-the-stable-homotopy-category) you already know that such exist), then the fiber $F\to X$ of $f$ induces an epimorphism on all homotopy groups without being a split epimorphism in the stable homotopy category.

Comment: Thanks Hanno, very nice answer.

Comment: You're welcome, jeffrey!